# can't create users or grant privileges on mysql db after reboot

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

I have a mysql db running on ubuntu server.  Originally it was v5.7, then I upgraded it to version 8.0.23.  I rebooted my ubuntu server recently, and now I don't seem to be able to create users or grant permissions.  I have an example where I tried creating two test users below, but I keep getting this MyISAM related error.  Does anyone know what the issue might be, and can you suggest how to fix?

```
mysql> create user 'testuser1'@'%%' identified by 'test1';
ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user]
```

I tried the suggestions in this post:

[How to fix ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. in Mysql 8.0 after CREATE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292491/how-to-fix-error-1726-hy000-storage-engine-myisam-does-not-support-system-t)

```
mysql> alter table mysql.db ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table mysql.columns_priv ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

but it didn't seem to fix it

```
mysql> create user 'test' identified by 'test';

ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user]
```

Comment: I do hope you took backups before you started all this

Comment: The link yuo are referring to has a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66444285/724039)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

What worked for me was stopping MySQL service.

```
service mysqld stop
```

Then running the following command to force an upgrade of the schemas.

```
mysqld --upgrade=FORCE
```

And then starting MySQL service again.

```
service mysqld start
```

After that everything started working fine.