# MySQL 8.0.32 #1449 - The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Tags: mysql

I'm having issue with MySQL server. We are not completely sure what happened before this error but MySQL is giving error message below. Error was noticed when one user logged to phpmyadmin:

#1449 - The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Many threads suggest that database should be upgraded. Syntax for this varies but I guess this is the correct procedure for this version? Can someone confirm?

1. Stop MySQL database: sudo systemctl stop mysqld
2. Run upgrade: sudo mysqld --upgrade=force --user=root
3. Check MySQL status:  systemctl status mysqld ( Active: active (running))

But the error is still there. Also mysqldump is not working so I cannot take backups.
Database is still functioning but it cannot be managed anyway.

/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log looks like this:

```
2023-09-21T17:05:56.566731Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 21695
2023-09-21T17:05:56.574246Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-21T17:05:57.245327Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-09-21T17:05:57.426636Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001287 - 'validate password plugin' is $
2023-09-21T17:05:57.609631Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-09-21T17:05:57.609688Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-09-21T17:05:57.620844Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user].
2023-09-21T17:05:57.620870Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.db].
2023-09-21T17:05:57.620891Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.tables_priv].
2023-09-21T17:05:57.620899Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.columns_priv].
2023-09-21T17:05:57.620905Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.procs_priv].
2023-09-21T17:05:57.620911Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.proxies_priv].
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621013Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013143] [Server] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 51, found 45. The table is probably corrupted
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621027Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621055Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621063Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621075Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621083Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621091Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621098Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621105Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.621112Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2023-09-21T17:05:57.627594Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010727] [Server] System table 'func' is expected to be transactional.
2023-09-21T17:05:57.633760Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution.
2023-09-21T17:05:57.633828Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysqlx.sock
```

Have tried

Upgrade: sudo mysqld --upgrade=force --user=root

Recreate user: CREATE USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

I read this: [How to fix ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. in Mysql 8.0 after CREATE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292491/how-to-fix-error-1726-hy000-storage-engine-myisam-does-not-support-system-t)

and

this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Then I ran these:
'''

```
alter table mysql.user ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table mysql.db ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table mysql.tables_priv ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table mysql.columns_priv ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table mysql.procs_priv ENGINE=InnoDB;
alter table mysql.proxies_priv ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

'''

And finally this sudo mysqld --upgrade=force --user=root
but the upgrade never finished. I let it run over night, 9 hours. So I'm stuck with this now.

Comment: Are you able to access the data using MySQl Workbench? (the superior version of phpadmin?)

Comment: Ohh saw this "MyISAM" error ... are you not using InnoDB tables or is this an old thing?  Also check the " error-log" as well ..

Comment: Databases were migrated from sometime ago from old server to new but unfortunately it's not clear what happened with this error.  I found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292491/how-to-fix-error-1726-hy000-storage-engine-myisam-does-not-support-system-t and now I'm trying to run these commands to all those system tables "alter table mysql.user ENGINE=InnoDB;"

Comment: Hope that thread does it for you

Comment: Anyway I'm not sure if this is the correct way to fix this. The upgrade has now taken 40minutes and there are no error messages. Thanks for the MySQL Workbench tip, going to give it a try.

Comment: Hopefully you get it going, and get MySQL Workbenc on there, its very good.  Phpadmin is great for a situation you need a php environment to get to the database.  But if you don't need that, you get much more control with direct access,  Godluck!

Comment: @easileyfixed: Please finally stop to promote workbench  in mostly every comment -The problem is SQL related and not UI related.